# Defining the cup product in Ext using a Kunneth formula

Tags: homological-algebra, cohomology, cup-product

I want to make a Kunneth product of sorts on Ext.  In particular, letting $C_*$ be a $R$-free resolution for $k$ over a $k$-hopf algebra $R$, elements in $Ext_R(k,k)$ are represented by maps in $Hom_R(C_*,k)$.  Of course, we can consider $Hom_R(C_* \otimes C_*,k)$, the cohomology of this being the same since $k\otimes k \cong k$.

What I want then is a sort of Kunneth product:

$$\times :Hom_R(C_*,k)\otimes Hom_R(C_*,k)\to Hom_R(C_*\otimes C_*,k).$$

I want it to be the case that this defines the cup product (aka Yoneda product).  If we get a magical map

$$\Delta : C_*\to C_*\otimes C_*,$$

then

$$\cup : Ext_R(k,k)\otimes Ext_R(k,k)\to Ext_R(k,k)$$

can be given, on the co-chain level,

$$(a\cup b)(\sigma) = (a\times b)(\Delta \sigma).$$

Now, $\Delta$ is possibly defined up to homotopy by the requirement that it commutes with the augmentation in $R$.

My question is this: is there a way to describe this Kunneth product using any $C_*$, or do I need to use a Bar resolution of sorts like in group cohomology. Does this method even make sense? Can you help flesh this out?

Thanks!

Comment: This is done in Cartan-Eilenberg.


Comment: I can't seem to improve on Mariano's observation...

Comment: I'm reading it on Google Books preview right now, and it seems to walk through my reasoning and clear up my confusion.  Thanks for the reference.  I think I'll grab a real copy when the library opens Monday.  

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: more than two years later I would like to ask: is there a more modern version of cartan-eilenberg? I've learned homological algebra using gelfand-manin, but there are many topics in cartan-eilenberg which I think are treated in greater detail. Is there a book that does that but using more modern language (perhaps even using derived categories?).

Comment: The cup product is just the composition of maps in the derived category. If you want to actually compute, that's not very helpful, though.

Comment: if you want to look at how to get steenrod operations as well take a  look at Bruner's work in either the $H_{\infty}$-ring spectra volume or in chapters 3/4 in his Adams SS primer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez:  Actually, composition of chain maps lifting the cocycles is often the easiest way to compute!

Comment: Sometimes, yes (specially when you only need to compute a few products, rather than the whole thing) but the reduction ofmcup products to conputations in the derived category is not a reduction, as the Principle of Conservation of Difficulty kicks in.

Comment: I'd say that if you really know how to lift cocycles to chain maps in an example, you also know how to write down the diagonal map :-)